# LinkedList in Scala

Tags: scala, linked-list

For exercise I'm trying to implement a `LinkedList` in Scala.

Main problem is about `Null` reference.

But first some code:

```
class Node(xkey: String, xnext: Option[Node], xinfo: Int) {
  val key: String = xkey;
  var next = xnext.getOrElse(None);
  var info: Int = xinfo;

  def this(xkey: String, xinfo: Int) {
    this(xkey, None, xinfo);
  }

  def this(xkey: String) {
    this(xkey, None, -1);
  }

  @Override
  override def toString: String = key + ":" + info
}
```

At this point, I'm already concerned about things.
I declare `xnext` in construct as a `Option[Node]`, because the tail in this `linkedList` does not have a next.

In my first try, it was just a `Node`, but had problem with null object because compilator just told me that "null can't cast to Node" (or something like that, I do not remember now) - And so I switch to this Option.

But, is it ok? Because, you know, for me next should be a `Node`, not a `Option`, otherwise, I don't know, in the `linkedList` how to reference to next Node.

Whatever, second class (i.e. my Linked List)

```
class LinkedNode {

  private var first: Option[Node] = None;
  private var last: Option[Node] = None;

  def addNode(newNode: Node) = {
    if (first == null) {
      first = Some(newNode);
      last = Some(newNode);
      first.next = last;
    }
    else {
      last.next = newNode;
      newNode.next = null;
      last = newNode
    }
  }

  def size(): Long = {
    var currentNode : = first;
    var size = 0L;
    while (currentNode != null) {
      size+=1;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    size
  }

  def findNodeByKey(key: String) : Node = {
    var currentNode = first;
    while(currentNode != null) {
      if (currentNode.key.equals(key))
        currentNode
      else {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }
    }
    currentNode;
  }

  def delNodeByKey(key : String) : Boolean = {
    var currentNode = first;
    var previousNode = first;
    while(currentNode != null) {
      if (currentNode.key.equals(key)) {
        previousNode = currentNode.next;
        return true;
      }
      previousNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return false;
  }


}
```

And nothing. I'm already block to my constructor because first and last.

How should I declare them? `Node`? Or `Option[Node]`?
Problems are also in `Add` method.
When I add a node, I want to add a `Node` object, not an `Option[Node]`.
And I don't get how to achieve things I want with all `Option`, `Some` and `None` classes.

I know I should not be so vague with my request, but any help?

P.S. I've already read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249272/java-style-linkedlist-in-scala) and it didn't help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At this point, I'm already concerned about things. I declare xnext in construct as a Option[Node], because the tail in this linkedList does not have a next.
>   [...]
>   But, is ok? because, you know, for me next should be a Node, not a Option, otherwise, I don't know, in the linkedList how to reference to next Node.

This is a good solution to replacing `null`, which you definitely want to do to prevent null-pointer exceptions and the like. An `Option[Node]` is simply a `Node` wrapped in a container (or `None`). You can check whether or not it has a value with `isEmpty` or get its value with `get` (which will throw an exception if the Option is empty).

The only difference to `null`, as you'd use it in Java, is that you need to check if it `isEmpty` instead of checking for null, and that you need to unwrap (`option.get`) it explicitly when you're sure that it is not `None`.

A more paradigmatic (scala-typical) way of retrieving the value from an option is pattern matching:

```
option match {
    case Some(x) => println(x)
    case None => println("Whoops, no value :(")
}
```

Regarding your other questions, they are indeed a little vague.

> How should I declere them? Node? or Option[Node]?

Use `Option[Node]` if the possibility exists that there's no value for the variable (i.e., if you'd set it to `null` sometimes in Java).

> When I add a node, I want to add a Node object, not a Option[Node].

No, you want to add an `Option[Node]` internally, because you will need to check later on if a node is set or not. In Scala it is preferrable to do this via `Option[Node].isEmpty` compared to setting things to null. You're already doing this in some parts of your code (e.g., `addNode`), where you do `Some(newNode)` (I'd call this "wrapping the node in an Option", but I'm not entirely sure if that's the correct terminology).

> And I don't get how to achieve things I want with all Option, Some and None class.

What you're doing in your `addNode` does seem correct to a degree, but you somehow try to use `null` again in the `else` branch. What about:

```
// We don't need Option[Node] for the parameter, because there 
// _must_ be a Node value to be added
def addNode(newNode: Node) = {
    if (first.isEmpty) {
        first = Some(newNode)
        last = Some(newNode)
        first.next = last
    } else {
        newNode.next = None
        last.next = Some(newNode)
        last = Some(newNode)
    }
}
```

(I didn't run that code, nor did I do an thorough check of your logic)

Comment: Thank you. You explanation really help me.